# how to identify which is a non-object in the code if it shows error as `trying to get property of non-object`?

Tags: php

After making some modifications to my existing script, I created an error:

> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object...

I am trying to figure how to identify if the variable `$result` is an object so I don't get this error (I am getting the error on this particular line `if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {` ). Here is what have:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM input WHERE id =".$_GET["id"]; 
$result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row -> $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $myid = $row["id"] ;
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM output WHERE question_id = $myid ORDER BY date DESC";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        $sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as rowCount FROM output WHERE question_id = '".$myid."'";

        $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
        $rowCount= $result3->fetch_assoc();
?>
```

How can I tell beforehand if this is an object or not?

Comment: I think you had run the query in procedural way and getting data in Object-oriented way is the reason for issue.

Comment: $result is not an object because your query failed, you need to debug that

Comment: As a side advice, don't you ever concatenate a GET parameter to a query without cleaning it or using prepared statements. Search for mysql injection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have the variable `$conn` initialized any where in the code before that? 
Second, you want to make your while loop like this: 
`while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ... }`

Comment: "Yes" , i have $conn included in the script. and "no" changing the -> to = didn't gave any clue..

Comment: guess what changing -> to = in `if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {` made `num_rows` a constant..

Comment: I am not sure, but could it be the space after the $result-> num_rows, and about the $result = $row->fetch_assoc() I got it from here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: earlier i thought the same, whether $ sign infront of num_rows can   be the reason but it didn't instead i even changed the -> to = but it kinda allowed space for new errors..

Comment: I suggest to debug your code, try to see the $results variable what it contains before executing the loop, like just comment out all the code after $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql), check it, and see where your code is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to find content is array or object :

```
is_object() to find object 
is_array() to find array 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM compt WHERE id =1"; 
$result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

    }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean, .. i presume my code is an object.

Comment: I mean how to check content is array or object. ...in you above code you have done mistake that's why its giving error .........it may be at $result-> num_rows

Comment: use this one ........if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
      
 }
 }

Comment: instead of  $row-> use '='   at while($row -> $result->fetch_assoc()) {

Comment: you mean this `if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`

Comment: Yes $row = $result->fetch_assoc()